# Swift SpriteKit intertestial Ads stop sound effects

Tags: swift, audio, ios8, effects

I am having an issue with my game that is on the app store. When you click and than watch a full screen ad (intertestial Ads) upon returning to the game all SKAction.playWithSound will not work anymore until I close the game. I have never seen this in testing before. This also sometimes happens to backgroundMusic that is AVAudioPlayer.
Any suggestions what could cause this?

Comment: can you tell me Xcode and iOS version

Comment: Hey. I am using the latest xCode version (6.4) and iOS 8.4. It is written in swift in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was fixed with a subsequent iOS / xCode update.